# How to remove the reminder that a program is still running in the background?

Tags: windows-11, skype, notification-area

When closing Skype (or another application that minimizes to the tray) I get **every time** the reminder

[image]

In Windows 10 it was a one-shot reminder, after which the OS assumed that I can read with understanding and that it does not need to remind me every time I close the app.

In Windows 11 this is not the case and it is driving me crazy.

There is the there dots menu (`···`) where I can "Turn off all notifications for Skype Enterprise" (or the relevant app). I do not want to turn off **all** notifications, but only that one.

Is there a way to end this madness?

Comment: Does this [manage notifications faq](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34811/how-do-i-manage-notifications-in-skype-on-desktop) apply here ?

Comment: @harrymc: unfortunately not - this is Skype Enterprise and it lacks the "Notifications" tab. Since the notification is an "OS" rather than an "Application" one (it is the OS that tells me that the app will be running, Skype is just an example here), I was hoping for a solution to durable such notifications globally.